# Multiple Products in one Cart magento 2.1 REST Api

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, android

i am sending POST request and its not working, i am hitting url `"www.sample.com/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/c62700b7e525b82c0e96607e11ec0942/items"`

```
{ "cartItem": [
  { "quote_id": "c62700b7e525b82c0e96607e11ec0942","sku": "8246549-Black-40", "qty":1 },
  { "quote_id": "c62700b7e525b82c0e96607e11ec0942","sku": "8544501-Brown-43", "qty":1 },
  { "quote_id": "c62700b7e525b82c0e96607e11ec0942","sku": "8516031-Black-44", "qty":1 }
 ]
}
```

ACTUAL RESULT: "message": "Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. **Report ID: webapi-5a4a0b000116e"**

Comment: please check log file for exceptions 
so you can get exact error and you can know what is missing in that.

Comment: Magento rest API only allow to add one item at a time.

Comment: Message: Property "0" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface". in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php @Magento2Learner

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7430
Check this magento team is telling that this is fixed.

Comment: @ShozibRasool Have you get any solution for add multiple product in rest API.
I have facing same issue.